# ADF Pipeline Adding Sequential Value in Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Apologies if this has been asked and answered elsewhere. If it is, please do refer to the url in comments on replies. So here is the situation,

I am making an API Request, in response I get **auth_token** which I use in the Copy Activity as Authorization to retrieve data in JSON format and Sink it to Azure SQL Database. I am able to Map all the elements I'm receiving in JSON to the columns of Azure SQL Database. However, there are two columns (**UploadId** and **RowId**) that still need to be populated.

- **UploadId** is a GUID which will be same for the whole batch of rows (this I've managed to solve)
- **RowId** will be a *sequence* starting from 1 to end of that batch entry, and then for next batch (with new GUID value) it resets back to 1.

The database will look something like this,

```
| APILoadTime |      UploadId     |    RowId    |
|  2020-02-01 | 29AD7-12345-22EwQ |      1      |
|  2020-02-01 | 29AD7-12345-22EwQ |      2      |
|  2020-02-01 | 29AD7-12345-22EwQ |      3      |
|  2020-02-01 | 29AD7-12345-22EwQ |      4      |
|  2020-02-01 | 29AD7-12345-22EwQ |      5      |
--------------------------------------------------> End of Batch One / Start of Batch Two
|  2020-02-01 | 30AD7-12345-22MLK |      1      |
|  2020-02-01 | 30AD7-12345-22MLK |      2      |
|  2020-02-01 | 30AD7-12345-22MLK |      3      |
|  2020-02-01 | 30AD7-12345-22MLK |      4      |
|  2020-02-01 | 30AD7-12345-22MLK |      5      |
--------------------------------------------------> End of Batch Two and so on ...
```

Is there a way in Azure Pipeline's Copy Activity to achieve this **RowId** behavior ... Or even if it's possible within Azure SQL Database.

Apologies for a long description, and Thank you in advance for any help!
Regards

Comment: Can you do it with Data Flow?

Comment: Good point @LeonYue, the process is that Copy Activity stores directly to the Table, once sinked, the Data Flow is run to transform the data and sink it to secondary Table (called TransformedTable). Maybe I can do it in that, but is there an activity within DataFlow I could use to achieve that? Thanks

Comment: I tried and I'm afraid there is no active can achieve that in Data Factory or Data Flow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Window Function to achieve this.  ADF Data Flows have [Window Transformation activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-window) that are designed to do this exact thing.

Otherwise, you could load the data into a staging table and then [use Azure SQL to window the data](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) as you select it out like...

```
SELECT
    APILoadTime
    ,UploadId
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UploadId ORDER BY APILoadTime) AS RowId
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Leon Yue and @JeffRamos, I've managed to figure out the solution, so posting it here for everyone else who might encounter the same situation,

The solution I found was to use a **Stored Procedure** within Azure Data Factory from where I call the Azure Data Flow Activity. This is the code I used for creating the RowId seed function,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE resetRowId
AS
BEGIN
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('myDatabase', RESEED, 0)
END
GO
```

Once I have this Stored Procedure, all I did was something like this,

[image: Azure Data Factory Pipeline Reset RowId]

This does it for you, the reason I kept it 0 so that when new data comes in, it starts from 1 again ...

Hope this helps others too ...

Thank you all who helped in someway

Comment: Ah.  In that case, you could have also just done "TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable" in the "Pre-copy script" field of the Sink tab of the Copy activity.  Glad you got it worked out either way.

Comment: Doesn't Truncate lose all existing data as well?!?

Comment: Correct, it does delete the data too.  It appeared that you were iterating over each load in batches, which is why I suggested that.  Usually the identity column is a PK or at least unique, but I think I see how you were able to make it work for your needs.  Clever.

I do still suggest looking at the window functions mentioned previously.  They'll allow you to do this sort of thing without relying on an identity column.  ROW_NUMBER is only one of the window functions too.  They're pretty slick.