# Add sequential custom column using copy activity in ADF

Tags: sequence, rowid, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV source and Azure SQL as a sink for a copy activity in the Azure data factory pipeline. I want to add a RowID column (not part of CSV) to the sink table with values as 1,2,3,4........ Is it possible to do this without the use of data flows? Thanks in advance

[ADF Pipeline Adding Sequential Value in Copy Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748519/adf-pipeline-adding-sequential-value-in-copy-activity/63800338#63800338)

(similar to the case in the above link but I need not reset the rowID)

Comment: do you mean create a new column RowID and insert them with csv data into Azure SQL database?

Comment: Does the Pipeline create the table? Do you need to control the new RowID value? Does it need to be truly sequential or just unique? If the answer to all of these is No, can you add an IDENTITY column to the Azure SQL Table?

Comment: @Joel Cochran The table is already created, the pipeline populates the table. It needs to be sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for now, only the Data Flow [Surrogate key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-surrogate-key) can help to create the new column (RowId) with sequential value . Copy active support add column, but can't set the sequential values like 1,2,3....

We can't achieve that with copy actives, it's impossible for now. Some other ways are that you need building the code with notebook or function active.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Sruthi56, you're welcome. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.